# Applying ifelse in multiple variables / columns for replacing 99 and 999 to NA

Tags: r, if-statement, lapply, missing-data

I have a dataframe with some columns where 99 should be considered as missing values (NA) and other columns where 999 was the value given for this purpose.

```
dat$variable1 <- ifelse(dat$variable1 == 99, NA, dat$variable1)
dat$variable2 <- ifelse(dat$variable2 == 99, NA, dat$variable2)
dat$variable3 <- ifelse(dat$variable3 == 99, NA, dat$variable3)
dat$variable4 <- ifelse(dat$variable4 == 99, NA, dat$variable4)
dat$variable5 <- ifelse(dat$variable5 == 999, NA, dat$variable5)
dat$variable6 <- ifelse(dat$variable6 == 999, NA, dat$variable6)
dat$variable7 <- ifelse(dat$variable7 == 999, NA, dat$variable7)
```

I'd like to find a better way to do that, because sometimes we can have many many columns to deal with. I don't know how to loop over the specific variables that I should replace these values for NA and I'm not aware of a package that could help me with that (I'm a beginner in R).

EDIT:
I have to apologise for a mistake I made in my question. I firstly posted `dat$variable1 <- ifelse(dat$variable1 == 99, NA, dat$EC)`, keeping "dat$EC" in all lines of code. Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider running `ifelse` on a block of columns since it works on vectors and matrices:

```r
var_99 <- c("variable1", "variable2", "variable3", "variable4")
var_999 <- c("variable5", "variable6", "variable7")

dat[var_99] <- ifelse(dat[var_99] == 99, NA, dat$EC)
dat[var_999] <- ifelse(dat[var_999] == 999, NA, dat$EC)
```

For more than one variable replacement, coerce the `no` argument to matrix:

```r
dat[var_99] <- ifelse(dat[var_99] == 99, NA, as.matrix(dat[var_99]))
dat[var_999] <- ifelse(dat[var_999] == 999, NA, as.matrix(dat[var_99]))
```

Comment: Hi, @Parfait. Unfortunately it didn't work. When I try it on my data, I get a Warning message: ` var_99 <- c("var1", "var2")` `dat[var_99] <- ifelse(dat[var_99] == 99, NA, dat[var_99])` `Warning message: In "[<-.data.frame"("tmp", var_99, value = list(c(4, 3, 3, 4, : provided 188 variables to replace 2 variables `  Although the following code works fine:  `dat$var1 <- ifelse(dat$var1 == 99, NA, dat$var1)`

Comment: I see you edited your original post away from single column `dat$EC`. For multiple columns, coerce the `no` argument with `as.matrix`. See edit.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake in my question, @Parfait. But now it is exactly the answer I was looking for. Simple and efficient. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If 99 and 999 are unique values for missing in your data frame `dat`, you could just:

```
dat[dat == 999] <- NA
dat[dat == 99] <- NA
```

If not, you could use `na_if` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat_1 <- dat %>%
  mutate(across(c(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4), na_if, 99),
         across(c(variable5, variable6, variable7), na_if, 999))
dat_1
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `dplyr::across`.

For a dummy data `dat` defined like

```
dat <- data.frame(
  variable1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,99),
  variable2 = c(1,2,99,4,5,6,7),
  variable3 = c(1:7),
  variable4 = c(5:11),
  variable5 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,999),
  variable6 = c(1,2,3,4,999,6,7),
  variable7 = c(1:7),
  EC = c(-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7)
)

  variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4 variable5 variable6 variable7 EC
1         1         1         1         5         1         1         1 -1
2         2         2         2         6         2         2         2 -2
3         3        99         3         7         3         3         3 -3
4         4         4         4         8         4         4         4 -4
5         5         5         5         9         5       999         5 -5
6         6         6         6        10         6         6         6 -6
7        99         7         7        11       999         7         7 -7
```

You may try this way.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(across(variable1:variable4, ~ifelse(.x == 99, NA, EC)),
         across(variable5:variable7, ~ifelse(.x == 999, NA, EC)))

  variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4 variable5 variable6 variable7    EC
      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1        -1        -1        -1        -1        -1        -1        -1    -1
2        -2        -2        -2        -2        -2        -2        -2    -2
3        -3        NA        -3        -3        -3        -3        -3    -3
4        -4        -4        -4        -4        -4        -4        -4    -4
5        -5        -5        -5        -5        -5        NA        -5    -5
6        -6        -6        -6        -6        -6        -6        -6    -6
7        NA        -7        -7        -7        NA        -7        -7    -7
```

If you know column indexes, like in my `dat`, from `variable1` to `variable4` is `1:4` and `variable5` to `variable7` is `5:7`, just using column indexes will give you the same result.

```
dat %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(across(1:4, ~ifelse(.x == 99, NA, EC)),
         across(5:7, ~ifelse(.x == 999, NA, EC)))

  variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4 variable5 variable6 variable7    EC
      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1        -1        -1        -1        -1        -1        -1        -1    -1
2        -2        -2        -2        -2        -2        -2        -2    -2
3        -3        NA        -3        -3        -3        -3        -3    -3
4        -4        -4        -4        -4        -4        -4        -4    -4
5        -5        -5        -5        -5        -5        NA        -5    -5
6        -6        -6        -6        -6        -6        -6        -6    -6
7        NA        -7        -7        -7        NA        -7        -7    -7
```

## Add

```
dat <- data.frame(
  variable1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,99),
  variable2 = c(1,2,99,4,5,6,7),
  variable3 = c(1:7),
  variable4 = c(5:10,999),
  variable5 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,99),
  variable6 = c(1,2,3,4,999,6,7),
  variable7 = c(1:7),
  EC = c(-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7)
)

dat %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(across(c(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable5), ~ifelse(.x == 99, NA, EC)),
         across(c(variable4, variable6, variable7), ~ifelse(.x == 999, NA, EC)))

  variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4 variable5 variable6 variable7    EC
      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1        -1        -1        -1        -1        -1        -1        -1    -1
2        -2        -2        -2        -2        -2        -2        -2    -2
3        -3        NA        -3        -3        -3        -3        -3    -3
4        -4        -4        -4        -4        -4        -4        -4    -4
5        -5        -5        -5        -5        -5        NA        -5    -5
6        -6        -6        -6        -6        -6        -6        -6    -6
7        NA        -7        -7        NA        NA        -7        -7    -7
```

Comment: What if the columns are not consecutive like that? I mean, what if var5 and var7 should have 99 as NA and var1 and var3 should have 999 as NA? Is there a way to replace `var1:var4` with, for example, a list of columns? ("var" I mean "variable" in my example)

Comment: @Allan I add the code above. Say `variable4` has 999 and `variable5` has 99. Then just specify those manually, then it will works.